# Prove a lower bound of the summation of a sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series

Let $a_1 = 1$ and
$$
    a_{n + 1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n} + 1 - \log a_n}
$$
for $n \geq 1$. We want to prove
$$
    \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i > \log (n + 1)
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Could anyone help me? Thanks so much.

PS: I let
$$
    f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 1 - \log x}
$$
then since $f'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x} - 2}{2x(\sqrt{x} + 1 - \log x)^2}$, we know that $f$ achieve its maximum value $\frac{1}{3 - \log 4}$ at $x = 4$. But I do not know how to do for the next step.

Comment: $a_n$ very quickly converges towards the fixed point $\approx 0.3895$, and we have $ \sum a_i > 0.3895n > \log(n+1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some thoughts**:

Since $\sqrt{x} - \ln x \ge 2 - \ln 4$ for all $x > 0$, we have $0 < a_n < 1$ for all $n\ge 2$.

We use Mathematical Induction to prove that $a_n \ge \ln(n + 1) - \ln n$
for all $n \ge 1$.

For $n = 1$, it is true.

Assume that it is true for $n$ ($n \ge 1$).

For $n+1$, by the inductive hypothesis,
noting that
$f(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 1 - \ln x}$
is strictly increasing on $(0, 2)$,
we have
$$
 a_{n+1} = f(a_n) \ge f(\ln(n + 1) - \ln n) \ge f\left(\frac{2}{2n + 1}\right)
$$
where we use $\ln(n + 1) - \ln n \ge \frac{2}{2n + 1}$ for all $n \ge 1$.
*Note*: We have $f'(x) = \frac{2 - \sqrt x}{2x(\sqrt x + 1 - \ln x)^2} > 0$
on $(0, 2)$.

It suffices to prove that
$$f\left(\frac{2}{2n + 1}\right)
\ge \ln(n + 2) - \ln(n + 1) \tag{1}$$
which is true. The proof of (1) is given at the end.

Thus, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \ge 
\sum_{k=1}^n [\ln(k + 1) - \ln k] = \ln(n + 1).$$

We are done.

*Proof of* (1):

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{2n + 1}} + 1 + \ln(n + 1/2)} \ge \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n + 1}\right). \tag{2}$$

If $n = 1, 2, 3$, (2) is directly verified.

If $n \ge 4$, using
$\ln(n + 1/2) \le n - 1/2$
and $\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n + 1}\right)
\le \frac{1}{n + 1}$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{2n + 1}} + 1 + n - 1/2} \ge \frac{1}{n + 1}$$
or
$$\frac12 \ge \sqrt{\frac{2}{2n + 1}}$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @香结丁 You are welcome.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks for comment. I edited it.